# How to add fractions and display the result as fraction?

Tags: php, class

```
public function add($temp) {
        $newNum = $this->num + $temp->num;
        if($this->denum == $temp->denum) {
               // add two fractions having same denominator
               $answer = $newNum . "/" . $this->denum;
        } else {
               // how to add two fractions having different denominator?
        }
        return $answer;
}
```

In other words, how to handle the case of two fractions having different denominators, like:

> 1/3 + 1/6 = 3/6

or

> 1/3 + 1/5 = 8/15

Comment: if echo its posible. but if value? *thinking

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths.

Comment: @X.L.Ant sorry I re edit it...

Comment: `$a = 1; $b = 1; $x = 3; $y = 6;
//$a .'/'. $x;
//$b .'/'. $y;
$a = (max($x, $y) - min($x, $y))-$a;
$newDivider = max($x, $y);
$newNum = ($a+$b) . '/' . $newDivider; echo $newNum;`

Comment: @DainisAbols but I want to be display like fraction not decimal

Comment: "[PHP convert decimal into fraction and back?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954018/php-convert-decimal-into-fraction-and-back)" is absolutely *not* a duplicate?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function gcd($num1, $num2) {
 /* finds the greatest common factor between two numbers */
    if ($num1 < $num2) {
        $t = $num1;
        $num1 = $num2;
        $num2 = $t;
    }
    while ($t = ($num1 % $num2) != 0) {
        $num1 = $num2;
        $num2 = $t;
    }
    return $num2;
}

public function add($temp) {
    $newNum = $this->num * $temp->denum + $temp->num * $this->denum;
    $newDenum = $temp->denum * $this->denum;
    $gcd = gcd($newNum, $newDenum);
    $newNum /= $gcd;
    $newDenum /= $gcd;
    return $newNum . '/' . $newDenum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to add 1/3 to 1/6, you simply do

```
$result = 1/3 + 1/6;
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants to simply calculate the result, he wants to display the formatted result, i.e. "3/6"

Comment: what? no need to separate the numerator and denum?

Comment: Numbers are numbers. You can simply display the result as a fraction if you so desire.

Answer (score 0):

This won't reduce fractions for you, but other than that it should do what you want:

```
public function add($temp) {
    if($this->denum == $temp->denum) {
        $newNum = $this->num + $temp->num;
        $answer = $newNum . "/" . $this->denum;
    } else {
        $newNum = $this->num * $temp->denum + $temp->num * $this->denum;
        $answer = $newNum . "/" . $this->denum*$temp->denum;
    }
    return $answer;
}
```