# Convert fraction to decimal in Php

Tags: php, sql, json

This is my code

```
<?php
Id  =$_GET['ID'];
error_reporting(0);
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("ehealth monitoring", $con); 
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT DateandTime,BP FROM table  WHERE ID='".$Id."'");
$rows = array();
$rows['name'] = 'BP';
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sth)) {
$rows['data'][] = [$r['DateandTime'],$r[eval('BP')]];
}
echo json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

In this code **BP** contains 100/77, 100/50, 99/45 kind of values. 
I want convert this values as decimal. I can't find my mistake. please help me to convert the values and pass value to json.

Comment: You're evaluating the string `BP` to PHP code. Not the value, but the string. Did you mean to use `eval($r['BP'])`? Neither the less, simple split the string on a slash and do regular division rather than relying on EVAL. What happens when malicious data is in your database and gets eval'd in your source code?

Comment: thank you for your reply.i have no idea about eval.. just i tried. how can i convert the value if you have any code ??@h2ooooooo

Comment: You know the value is going to be `number/number`. Split with `$fractions = explode('/', $r['BP'])` and calculate it like `$fractions[0] / $fractions[1]`. Also note that your code is using an outdated `mysql` library (use `mysqli_` or `PDO`) and your code is open to SQL injection (you need to escape or bind your variables).

Comment: See accepted asnwer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954018/php-convert-decimal-into-fraction-and-back/1954030

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function will help you, feel free to modify the function as per your need.

```
   <?php
    echo convertToDecimal ("100/77");

    function convertToDecimal ($fraction)
    {
        $numbers=explode("/",$fraction);
        return round($numbers[0]/$numbers[1],6);
    }
    ?>
```

This function will convert fraction to decimal.

Comment: Does not work properly for i.e. "1 3/32". Result should be 1.09375 instead of 0.03125

Answer (score 0):

A small extension to the function above:

```php
<?php
echo convertToDecimal ("100/77/22");
function convertToDecimal($sFraction, $iPrecision = 6, $sFractionSign = '/')
{
    $aNumbers = explode($sFractionSign, $sFraction);
    $fResult = $aNumbers[0];
    //user wrote a fraction with at least one $sFractionSign
    if (count($aNumbers) != 1) {
        array_shift($aNumbers);
        foreach ($aNumbers as $iNumber) {
            $fResult /= $iNumber;
        }
    }
    return round($fResult, $iPrecision);
}
```

Comment: fyi this does not work as expected. e.g. for "5/10" it gives 0.1 instead of 0.5

Comment: Indeed, the first number was also part of the loop resulting in 5/5/10 = .1. An array shift was missing which I added