# Convert .5 into 1/2

Tags: php

I want to convert any number which ends in .5 so that it displays as the number followed by ½, but I don't want 0.5 to display as 0½ so I did it like this:

```
$used = str_replace("0.5", "&frac12;", $used);
$used = str_replace(".5", "&frac12;", $used);
```

However I've now realised that this also converts 20.5 into 2½ instead of 20½.

I'm sure there's a better way of doing it but I don't know how.

**Examples:**

```
5 returns "5"
5.5 returns "5&frac12;"
0.5 returns "&frac12;"
10.5 returns "10&frac12;"
```

I don't believe this is a duplicate of an existing question because that code is to replace or return "1/2" rather than "½"

Comment: can you list some condition on which fraction should be done and and on what not to be done

Comment: `if( $used == "0.5" ) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP convert decimal into fraction and back?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954018/php-convert-decimal-into-fraction-and-back)

Comment: @AndyGroom Can my post, hope it will work fine.

Comment: @AndyGroom Is it fine now or do i change it for further requirement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting float decimal to fraction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330713/converting-float-decimal-to-fraction)

Comment: @Jadeye: That's a very different question than the one asked here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/769994)(In HTML it will work fine)

```
<?php
$number="10.5000";
if(preg_match("/^[1-9][0-9]*\.5[0]{0,}$/", $number))
{
    echo $used = preg_replace("/\.5[0]{0,}$/", "&frac12;", $number);
}
elseif(preg_match("/^[0]*\.5[0]{0,}$/", $number))
{
    echo $used = str_replace("$number", "&frac12;", $number);
}
else
{
    echo $number;
}
```

**Output:**
`10½`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, is it because your sample entry ends in a zero (ie. like currency) whereas my numbers are unformatted. My values will be like 10.5 rather than 10.50

Comment: @AndyGroom It will work fine for that as well you can check. I have updated my post keeping all the requirements in mind, specified by you.

Comment: *"I don't want 0.5 to display as 0½"*. What happens if `$number` is "0.5"?

Comment: @JJJ then it just returns &frac12;

Comment: @Sahilgulati my mistake sorry

Comment: @AndyGroom This code does *not* return just "&frac12;".

Comment: The body of the second branch can be simplified to: `echo "&frac12;";`.

Comment: @NisseEngström I have updated my post, can you please check again. If still there is any issue, can you let me know

Comment: @JJJ I have updated my post, can you please check again. If still there is any issue, can you let me know

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is extremely convoluted for a simple task. `if($number=="0.5") { $number="&frac12;"; } else { $number=str_replace(".5", "&frac12;", $number);}`

Comment: @JJJ What you are saying is correct but there can be a case when we have a number like this `10.5000`  then it will return like this `10½000` which is invalid. that's why i have handled it this way. But i dont know why people are downvoting :(

Comment: You don't know if there can be such a case. The OP didn't say anything like that, it's possible that it's guaranteed that there are no trailing zeroes.

Comment: Even if there can be trailing zeroes this could be done with one line of regex.

Comment: @JJJ Sorry to say sir, I am not arguing just take a case when number is `10.566`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the examples above and lacking any further requirements, you could write:

```
<?php

  $n = "13.5";
  /* ... */
  $r = $n;
  $r = preg_replace ('/^0\.5$/', '&frac12;', $r);
  $r = preg_replace ('/\.5$/', '&frac12;', $r);

  echo "$r\n";
```

You can combine the above into a single replacement:

```
  $r = preg_replace ('/(^0|)\.5$/', '&frac12;', $n);
```