# Returning a fraction

Tags: php

I'm using this function to return a number which ends in .5 as a html ½ so 6.5 would become 6½ but for some reason 15.5 comes out as ½½, what should it be please?

```
function Fractionalise($value) {
 if ($value=="0.5") {
  $value = "&frac12;";
 }
 else {
  if (preg_match("/\.5[0]{0,}$/", $value)) $value = preg_replace("/.5[0]{0,}/", "&frac12;", $value);
 }
 return $value;
}
```

Comment: Your else clause makes no sense

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43254282/convert-5-into-1-2 might be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in the preg_replace function you forgot an \.

It should be like

```
preg_replace("/\.5[0]{0,}/", "&frac12;", $value)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't escape `.`, then it means "match any character". Small typo, but changes a lot.

You could simplify your code

```
function Fractionalise($value) {
  return preg_replace("/\.50*/", "&frac12;", $value);
}
```