# multiplay a string of character by an integer

Tags: php

I need to display a fraction in PHP. For that I wrote:

$a = 3;

$b = 2;

$c = "$a/$b";

echo $c; // this displays 3/2
but on the other hand I want to multiply $c by an integer;

echo $c * 2; // this shows me an error

this is what shows me : ( ! ) Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- remove the double quote around operations (`$a/$b`) because it mean it is a string not an integer or float

  ```
  $a = 3;
  $b = 2;
  $c = $a/$b; 
  echo $c * 2;
  ```
- to display fraction it is another story

maybe look at this
[PHP convert decimal into fraction and back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954018/php-convert-decimal-into-fraction-and-back/1954030)

- or use this function

  ```
  function decimalToFraction($decimal){

      if ($decimal < 0 || !is_numeric($decimal)) {
          // Negative digits need to be passed in as positive numbers
          // and prefixed as negative once the response is imploded.
          return false;
      }
      if ($decimal == 0) {
          return [0, 0];
      }

      $tolerance = 1.e-4;

      $numerator = 1;
      $h2 = 0;
      $denominator = 0;
      $k2 = 1;
      $b = 1 / $decimal;
      do {
          $b = 1 / $b;
          $a = floor($b);
          $aux = $numerator;
          $numerator = $a * $numerator + $h2;
          $h2 = $aux;
          $aux = $denominator;
          $denominator = $a * $denominator + $k2;
          $k2 = $aux;
          $b = $b - $a;
      } while (abs($decimal - $numerator / $denominator) > $decimal * $tolerance);

      return [
          $numerator,
          $denominator
      ];
  }
  ```

source https://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/converting-a-decimal-to-a-fraction-in-php/